# ruby - delete from a string

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following strings:

```
src = "dav://w.lvh.me:3000/Home/Transit/file"
host = "w.lvh.me:3000"
```

What I want to obtain is `"/Home/Transit/file"` using those two strings

I thought of searching for `host` in `src` and delete it the first time it appears, and everything before it, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. Or maybe there's a better way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a better way indeed:

```
require 'uri'
src = "dav://w.lvh.me:3000/Home/Transit/file"
src = URI.parse src

src.path      # => "/Home/Transit/file"
```

When there are spaces in the string, you must pass extra step of escaping/unescaping. Fortunantly, this is simple:

```
require 'uri'
src = "dav://w.lvh.me:3000/Home/Transit/Folder 144/webdav_put_request"
src = URI.parse(URL.escape src)

URL.unescape(src.path)      # => "/Home/Transit/Folder 144/webdav_put_request"
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Not everything should be boiled down to a regular expression. You want a URI parser for parsing URIs, not yet another busted regular expression.

Comment: i forgot to ask, what if there are spaces in `src` ? URI.parse raises an error for example if `src = "dav://w.lvh.me:3000/Home/Transit/Folder 144/webdav_put_request"`

Comment: Thank you. I tried escaping with a custom function but I think it did not escape right. URI.escape works ok!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
src = "dav://w.lvh.me:3000/Home/Transit/file"
host = "w.lvh.me:3000"
result = src.sub(/.*#{host}/, '')
#=> "/Home/Transit/file"
```